# OSX 10.7.4 w/XCode 4.4.1 & GCC (Issues w/compiling straight C/C++)

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

The issue I'm having is that gcc (and family) don't appear to be properly setup. I have a 10.7.4 machine that I just installed Xcode on (from the app store). I've done no prior development on this machine.

Working w/in Xcode seems to work fine. I can build and compile no problem. However, trying to execute gcc command line fails.

First, I gcc wasn't on my path ... no big deal. I located it and ran as:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -dynamiclib -fno-common -o s.dylib s.c
```

(I'm working on a lib w/some functions...). Anyways, it fails.

```
s.c:1:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
s.c:2:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
s.c:3:20: error: string.h: No such file or directory
```

Surprise! hah, well I searched my machine for stdio.h and I can't find it anywhere. Since I've been out of the OSX game for a bit, I'm assuming I'm missing something -

Basically I want to be able to continue using Xcode but I want to be able to build C/C++/etc on the command line with all the dependencies (.h) in the correct place.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways to run the compiler from the command line: the Command Line Tools package, and xcrun.

`xcrun` is particularly good if you just need this occasionally. Just stick "xcrun" at the start, like you'd do with sudo:

```
xcrun gcc -dynamiclib -fno-common -o s.dylib s.c
```

This will find the correct version of gcc and set the needed directories, etc. You can specify a specific SDK with `--sdk`.

If you do this a lot, download and install the Command Line Tools package (Xcode>Open Developer Tool>More Tools...; it also may be available in Preferences>Downloads). This installs a full copy of everything in /usr.

Answer (score 0):

Probably xcrun is not enough if you are using 10.8.
Looking in to the clang documentation I found that you need to include the system root because you do not have your libraries in the standard place but inside Xcode.

using:

```
xcrun gcc -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
```

or:

```
xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
```